# How to navigate through all the values of an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a function that will get every key "quantidade", take their values, and multiply for the corresponding "tecnologia" key of the parent key, if the object has the "A" key in "tecnologia", it will multiply for the "A" value in the first object, this is what i did so far:

```
function calcula (tabela, arvore) {
    for (i = 0; i < arvore.length; i++) {
        arrFilhos = [`["filhos"][x]`]
        arrArvore = [`arvore[i]`]
        arrLevel = []

        for(x = 0; x < arvore[i]["filhos"].length; x++){
            if ("filhos" in eval(arrArvore[0])){
                console.log(eval(arrArvore.toString().replace(/,/g , "")))
                arrArvore.push(arrFilhos[0])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have infinite levels of filhos? Is the 2nd example (quantidade: 5) correct?

Comment: Yes its correct, the problem is that i can't figure out how to get in all the levels, it just don't work, no matter what i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that tecnologia only exists in the last node

```
function calculaCusto (tabelaCusto, arvoreArquitetura) {
   const cb = (prev, next) => {
     if(next.tecnologia) {
       return prev + next.quantidade * tabelaCusto[next.tecnologia];
     }
     else if(next.filhos){
       return prev + next.quantidade * next.filhos.reduce(cb, 0);
     } else { //doesn't have tecnologia nor filhos
       return;
     }
   }

   return arvoreArquitetura.reduce(cb, 0);
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem, but it still have to multiply their value for the parents "quantidade", the current output is 7675.6, which is correct, but it have to be multiplied by the parents "quantidade", is there any way to get the parents value?

Comment: so it needs to be 2* ( 2A + 3B) + 5 * 3* (1B + 4C)?

Comment: yes, and then sum the two values, the full formula is:
((2*A + 3*B) * 2) + ((1*B + 4*C) * 3 * 5)

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: that's it, thank you so much!